# selecting a max function value and it's corresponding id value from a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

The task is to get the result of the highest number of bookings and its corresponding facility id.
I thought to extract it from a subquery that is grouped by facility id and has a sum aggregate function. Then in the outer query, I will use the max function. But it doesn't work. It is printing all the facility and their sum of bookings. What is the problem?

```
select
    facid,
    max(total)
from
    (
        select
            facid,
            sum(slots) as total
        from
            cd.bookings
        group by
            facid
    ) as result
group by
    facid;
```

Comment: You want the one `facid` from the table whose sum of `slots` is maximum? What if there are two with the same maximal sum?

Comment: if there are multiple values equals max, I want everything. if not only a single value

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is, You're finding `SUM` first and `MAX` of that SUM by grouping by `FACILITYID` which will print MAX for each facilityid.

Instead, you should skip `GROUP BY` and get the `facilityID` by summing in outer query. Here is how you can do it:

**#Query 1** *(using nested subquery)*:

First we sum the slots for each facilityid, then we find max (overall), then we add a condition HAVING `SUM=MAX`

```
/* Using nested sub-queries */

select facilityid, sum(slot) as total
from booking
group by facilityID
having sum(slot) = 
 (
  select max(total) 
  from
  (
    select facilityID, sum(slot) as total
    from booking
    group by facilityID
  ) as sqsum
 )
```

**#Query 2** *(Using RANK)*:

Here, we simply find the sum and rank them in DESCENDING, then we filter with `RANK=1`:

```
/* Using RANK */

select facilityID, total
from(
SELECT 
   facilityID,
   sum(slot) as total, 
   rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(slot) DESC) AS rank
 from booking
 group by facilityID
 ) as rnk
 WHERE rank=1
```

**Note-** In both scenarios, more than 1 facilityid might be displayed if number of slots is same.

Sample results [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=722dd1a13ad865175caedf431a6b6578) - Check with all scenarios by updating input table

Comment: thanks. for multiple solutions.  is the rank function works in PostgreSQL? I am learning SQL in PostgreSQL. This can be done by sorting sum(slots) desc and then using limit 1 in PostgreSQL. But it has a weakness. it won't show multiple facility id if they have max slots. Rank function solves it. I know it's available in the SQL server.

Comment: `rank()` exists in PostgreSQL, and I think that is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use a Join;

```
WITH fac_booking AS (
SELECT facid, SUM(slot) AS factotal
FROM bookings
group by facid
),
max_booking AS (
SELECT MAX(factotal) AS maxtotal
FROM fac_booking
)
SELECT facid, factotal AS total
FROM fac_booking f
JOIN max_booking m ON f.factotal = m.maxtotal;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d47ae31cda0a6f54caac2af21d9ba7e)